# laravel Illegal operator and value combination when check is checkboxs is checked

Tags: php, laravel

When I send by POST method my form I need to check that checkbox is checked. In my controller I have 4 if's where I check that but when I do that I get error

> Illegal operator and value combination.

**My view**

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'PersonsController@raport', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Personel:</label>
        <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" name="data" id="data" value="{{date('Y-m-01')}}" width="100%" readonly/>
        {!! $errors->first('data', '<strong><p style="color:red;" class="help-block">:message</p></strong>') !!}     
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" name="all" type="checkbox" value="1" id="all">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
                All
            </label>            
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">User </label>
        {!! Form::select('users', $users, null, ['class'=>'form-control form-control-sm', 'placeholder'=>'All users']) !!}
        {!! $errors->first('users', '<strong><p style="color:red;" class="help-block">:message</p></strong>') !!}
    </div>
    {{Form::submit('Raport', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary btn-sm'])}}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

**and controller**

```php
 public function raport(Request $request)
    {
       //... some code

        if($request->input('all') !== 'on' && empty($request->input('users')))
        {
           $raport = Users::where('data', '>=', $request->input('data'))
            ->orderBy('id_users', 'asc')->get();
        }
        elseif($request->input('all') === 'on' && !empty($request->input('users')))
        {
            $raport = Users::where('id_users', $request->input('users'))
              ->orderBy('id_users', 'asc')->get();
        }
        elseif($request->input('all') === 'on' && empty($request->input('users')))
        {
            $raport = Users::orderBy('id_users', 'asc')->get();
        }
        elseif($request->input('all') !== 'on' && !empty($request->input('users')))
        {
            $raport = Users::where('id_users', $request->input('users'))
             ->where('data', '>=', $request->input('data'))
               ->orderBy('id_users', 'asc')->get();
        }
//... another some code
}
```

Comment: Why use the date sended via the form when it is the current date? It would be better to use `date('Y-m-01')` again

Answer (score 0):

you had this value

```
   <input class="form-check-input" name="all" type="checkbox" value="1" id="all">
```

it means you send value checkbox = **1**

if you didn't set the value then it has a default value as = **on**

therefore comparing integer into string resulting your error

and in your case, laravel had has method in request , so you can check whether checkbox in your form was checked or not

you can apply it in your code like this

```
    if(!$request->has('all') && empty($request->input('users')))
    {
       $raport = Users::where('data', '>=', $request->input('data'))
        ->orderBy('id_users', 'asc')->get();
    }
    elseif($request->has('all') && !empty($request->input('users')))
    {
        $raport = Users::where('id_users', $request->input('users'))
          ->orderBy('id_users', 'asc')->get();
    }
    elseif($request->has('all') && empty($request->input('users')))
    {
        $raport = Users::orderBy('id_users', 'asc')->get();
    }
    elseif(!$request->has('all') && !empty($request->input('users')))
    {
        $raport = Users::where('id_users', $request->input('users'))
         ->where('data', '>=', $request->input('data'))
           ->orderBy('id_users', 'asc')->get();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest first of all this code refactoring:

```php
public function raport(Request $request)
{
    //... some code
    if(!$request->has('all')){
        $date=date('Y-m-01');
        if(!$request->filled('users')){
            $query = Users::where('data', '>=', $date);
        }else{
            $query = Users::where('id_users', $request->input('users'))->where('data', '>=', $date);
        }
    }else{
        if(!$request->filled('users')){
            $query = Users::all();
        }else{
            $query = Users::where('id_users', $request->input('users'));
        }
    }
    $raport=$query->orderBy('id_users', 'asc')->get();
    //... another some code
}
```

It may not solve your problem, but it's clearer.

**Notes:**

- The error `Illegal operator and value combination` may be due to a comparison between a null value and a field (such as dateTime)
- If you would like to determine if a value is present on the request and is not empty, you may use the `filled` method

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I found that I was passing the null value in a variable.